# Update mysql query with IF statement

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql-update

I *only* want these update query to work *if* the event happened. The problem I'm facing is whichever the last query is is overriding the first one and even worse, this update query doesn't even update with the `if` statement. I've tried to change a lot of things.
What am I doing wrong?

```
    <?php
    $logout_button="header(location:'logout.php')";
    if ($logout_button){
    $logged_out="offline";
    $useronline_sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET status = '$logged_out' WHERE username='$username'");
 }?>




<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
 var moved = false
 window.onmousemove = function(e){
  if(!moved){
      moved = true;
         <?php
         $stat = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET status='online' WHERE email='$email'", $dbh2);
         ?>
  }}})()
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your page is requested, all the PHP code is run, and the HTML and javascript is sent to the browser. So both your SQL queries will be executed and the browser will be sent the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
var moved = false
window.onmousemove = function(e){
if(!moved){
     moved = true;

}}})() 
</script>
```

which won't do anything. You'll probably need to use ajax to send the request to another PHP page that runs your second query.